# How to set Measurement, Field/tag key and values in telegraf?

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I have a sensor network that uses MQTT. I am planning of using TICK stack and was stuck at telegraph configuration.

From Online resource, I understand that Telegraph can be configures to received messages from MQTT Broker.

subscription topic looks like this  `'+/update/#'`
And One of the received message from broker will look like this
topic name: `02000001000047F9/update/zb/dev/6/ldev/humidity/data/humidity payload: {"key":"humidity","name":"Relative Humidity","type":"double","unit":"% RH","access":"r","lastUpdated":"2019-01-11T09:29:18.327","value":34.0}`

As I understand in order to  put the data into influxdb one needs to specify "measurement", "tags" and "Fields" . One thing that's not clear is that how telegraf is converting the above topic & payload from MQTT Broker into "measurement", "tags" and "Fields" ? What will be "measurement", "tags" and "Fields" in above case ?

Secondly, if i want to group all the humidity data from different sensors zb/dev/1/, zb/dev/2/,zb/dev/3/ using some kind of processing plugin how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Configure your MQTT broker in the telegraf.conf file, in the `[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]` section. There you can set the connection data and the topics to listen. Be aware that it will ignore all string values, except the ones you define in the `json_string_fields` parameter.

Then the data will be loaded to the DB and accesible through the chronograf interface. You can send some queries in the explore section. You will have to work with an SQL like language. This is where you can try to work a solution to answer your second question.